# How to get Domains from a forest from Active Directory over LDAP SSL in c#

Tags: c#, ssl, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I am currently using the following code to get Domains from current forest.

```
Forest currentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
DomainCollection domainCollection = currentForest.Domains;
```

This method uses LDAP protocol to talk to AD, which is over port 389.
I am looking for an alternative to make the same call over port 636 (LDAP SSL).

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem to be possible. `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` uses  [`System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f6c52b913b2449297c54f9ab4802812d6c3bf7eb/src/libraries/System.DirectoryServices/src/System/DirectoryServices/ActiveDirectory/DirectoryEntryManager.cs#L272) which in turn [uses ADSI underneath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices?view=net-5.0) to get the data:

> #### System.DirectoryServices Namespace
>
> Provides easy access to Active Directory Domain Services from managed code. The namespace contains two component classes, DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher, which use the Active Directory Services Interfaces (ADSI) technology.

ADSI itself supports [two types of encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/binding-with-encryption): Kerberos-based and SSL-based. From the documentation:

> #### Kerberos-based Encryption
>
> To use Kerberos-based encryption, specify the `ADS_USE_SEALING` flag when calling `ADsOpenObject` or `IADsOpenDSObject::OpenDSObject`. The `ADS_USE_SEALING` flag can also be used to verify data integrity, that is, to ensure the data received is the same as the data sent. If the `ADS_USE_SEALING` flag is specified, the `ADS_USE_SIGNING` flag is automatically specified as well. Both flags require Kerberos authentication, which works only under the following conditions:
>
> - The client computer must be logged on to the Windows domain, or to a domain trusted by a Windows domain.
> - `ADsOpenObject` or `IADsOpenDSObject::OpenDSObject` must be called with null credentials; that is, alternate credentials cannot be specified.
>
> #### SSL-based Encryption
>
> To use SSL-based encryption, specify the `ADS_USE_SSL` flag when calling `ADsOpenObject` or `IADsOpenDSObject::OpenDSObject`. If only the `ADS_USE_SSL` flag is specified, ADSI opens SSL port 636 and then performs a simple bind over that SSL channel. If both the `ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION` and `ADS_USE_SSL` flags are specified, the binding behavior depends on the client that the call is made from. On unsupported versions of Windows, ADSI first opened an SSL channel and performs a simple bind using the specified user name and password or the current user context if both user name and password are null. On supported versions of Windows, ADSI performs a secure authentication rather than a simple bind.

This means that in order to do SSL authentication one needs to specify additional flag for ADSI binding. This is not configurable within `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory`, as the relevant [code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f6c52b913b2449297c54f9ab4802812d6c3bf7eb/src/libraries/System.DirectoryServices/src/System/DirectoryServices/ActiveDirectory/DirectoryEntryManager.cs#L261) says:

```cs
AuthenticationTypes authType = Utils.DefaultAuthType;

if (useServerBind)
{
    authType |= AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind;
}

de = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, username, password, authType);
```

These authentication flags are hardcoded to be `Utils.DefaultAuthType`, which is [defined](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f6c52b913b2449297c54f9ab4802812d6c3bf7eb/src/libraries/System.DirectoryServices/src/System/DirectoryServices/ActiveDirectory/Utils.cs#L49) as:

```cs
internal const AuthenticationTypes DefaultAuthType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.Signing | AuthenticationTypes.Sealing;
```

Therefore you cannot specify additional flag of [`AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f6c52b913b2449297c54f9ab4802812d6c3bf7eb/src/libraries/System.DirectoryServices/src/System/DirectoryServices/AuthenticationTypes.cs#L31) to get SSL encryption, BUT the standard set of flags is compatible with Kerberos encryption which ADSI enables by default. If you meet requirements (domain-joined computer with no custom credentials), the communication will be automatically encrypted with Kerberos, without any further setup. This can be verified with Wireshark (note the initial read of rootDSE anonymously in plain, bind request and all following communication with encrypted payload):

[image: Wireshark LDAP traffic]